# Dynamically created custom form components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/no1melman/3223e5c02506573776439cd1d95620ed) for the complete picture.

Basically I will have this form:

[image: form]

When you click the plus, another row should appear with a drop down for day and a time field.

I can create the code to add inputs to the form, however I'm having trouble with the individual components (`selectTimeInput` is a row) actually updating their values.

The `onChange` in the `MultipleDayTimeInput` is receiving the correct data, it is just the display that isn't updating. I extremely new to react so I don't know what is causing the display to not update....

I think it is because the `SelectTimeInput` render function isn't being called because the passed in `props` aren't being updated, but I'm not sure of the correct way to achieve that.

Thinking about it, does the `setState` need to be called in the `onChange` of the `MultipleDayTimeInput` and the input that changed needs to be removed from the `this.state.inputs` and readded in order to force the render to fire... this seems a little clunky to me...

Comment: can you post code? i have an idea of what it could be, but I need to see some code

Comment: right at the top of the post is a gist link! @jakeaaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update the display value of the inputs in state, you need to use `this.setState` to change the state data and cause a re-render with the new data. Using input.key = value is not the correct way.

> Using State Correctly
>   There are three things you should know about
>   setState().
>
> Do Not Modify State Directly
>   For example, this will not re-render a
>   component:
>
> // Wrong
>   this.state.comment = 'Hello';
>   Instead, use setState():
>
> // Correct
>   this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});
>   The only place where you
>   can assign this.state is the constructor.

read more from Facebook directly [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

I would actually suggest a little bit of a restructure of your code though. It's not really encouraged to have components as part of your state values. I would suggest having your different inputs as data objects in your this.state.inputs, and loop through the data and build each of the displays that way in your render method. Like this:

suppose you have one input in your this.state.inputs (and suppose your inputs is an object for key access):

```
inputs = {
    1: {
        selectedTime: 0:00,
        selectedValue: 2
    }
}
```

in your render, do something like this:

```
render() {
    let inputs = Object.keys(this.state.inputs).map((key) => {
        let input = this.state.inputs[key]
        return (<SelectTimeInput
            key={key}
            name={'option_' + key}
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            options={this.props.options}
            onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, key)}
            timeValue={input.selectedTime}
            selectValue={input.selectedValue} 
         />)      
    )}
    return (
        <div>
            <button className="button" onClick={this.onAddClick}><i className="fa fa-plus" /></button>

            { inputs }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Notice how we're binding the key on the onChange, so that we know which input to update. now, in your `onChange` function, you just set the correct input's value with setState:

```
onChange(event, key) {
    this.setState({
        inputs: Immutable.fromJS(this.state.inputs).setIn([`${key}`, 'selectedTime'], event.target.value).toJS()

        // or
        inputs: Object.assign(this.state.inputs, Object.assign(this.state.inputs[key], { timeValue: event.target.value }))

    })
}
```

this isn't tested, but basically this Immutable statement is going to make a copy of this.state.inputs and set the selectedTime value inside of the object that matches the key, to the event.target.value. State is updated now, a re-render is triggered, and when you loop through the inputs again in the render, you'll use the new time value as the `timeValue` to your component.

again, with the Object.assign edit, it isn't tested, but learn more [here]. [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) Basically this statement is merging a new timeValue value in with the this.state.inputs[key] object, and then merging that new object in with the entire this.state.inputs object.

does this make sense?

Comment: Could you just show the `Immutable` alternative in pure js? I don't want to start sticking `Immutable` in here just yet.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet those object assignment statements aren't exactly correct, but hopefully it gives you the right idea, and you can learn more about Object.assign with the link i provided in the edited answer

Comment: Yeah I know `Object.assign` fortunately!

Comment: great! then you know the implementation, so the basic idea is not to edit state objects directly, and use setState to cause a re-render in the correct way!

Comment: Just so you know `setState` will accept a function with the first argument as `prevState`. You can use this to replace using `this.state` inside of your set state. This is preferred because `setState` calls are batches and this will ensure the values are set properly.

Comment: @kwelch so if you are basing new state off of old state, then you should always use the `prevState  => ({})` function expression (well, a function)

Comment: I am not sure it is specifically outlines anywhere but that has always been my approach mainly because of the batching of the calls.

Comment: @kwelch it really does make sense though, if the `setState` is non-deterministic, then to use the current state it needs to be the state at the time you wish to change it otherwise you'll see annoying side effects cause buggy code.

Comment: I prefer pure functions and if you use it as a function it is more natural to move into a global state management system where all changes are central.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the `onChange` in the `MultipleDayTimeInput`:

```
onChange(event) {
    const comparisonKey = event.target.name.substring(event.target.name.length - 1);
    const input = this.getInputState(comparisonKey);

    input.selected = event.target.value;
    input.display = this.renderTimeInput(input);

    let spliceIndex = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.inputs.length; i++) {
        const matches = inputFilter(comparisonKey)(this.state.inputs[i]);

        if (matches) {
            spliceIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (spliceIndex < 0) {
        throw 'error updating inputs';
    }

    this.setState({
        inputs: [...this.state.inputs].splice(spliceIndex, 1, input)
    });
}
```

The key points are:

```
// re render the input
input.display = this.renderTimeInput(input);

// set the state by copying the inputs and interchanging the old input with the new input....
this.setState({
    inputs: [...this.state.inputs].splice(spliceIndex, 1, input)
});
```

Having thought about it though, `input` is an object reference to the input in the `this.state.inputs` so actually `[...this.states.inputs]` would have been enough??